# Should I mention my co-authors while tweeting about our publications?

Tags: etiquette, collaboration, social-media

Assume we have a paper published in a conference or journal. Should I mention my co-authors while posting some content of the paper (or just paper's link) on Twitter or Facebook?

Let's assume I am aware of their Twitter or Facebook accounts.

Comment: I would like to counter with the inverse question. _Is there a reason why you wouldn't mention your co-authors if you are aware of their accounts?_  We haven't been given any reason for a "Why not?"

Comment: Here's an obvious reason: 140 characters. And some papers have lots of coauthors. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16759/is-there-an-inflation-in-the-number-of-authors-per-paper

Comment: @AaronHall nothing stops people from sending additional tweets, though. This isn't like an abstract :/

Comment: If it takes more than a single tweet, you need a blog.

Answer (score 7):

It would be a polite thing to do to at least link the co-authors, for example, something along the lines of:

> Paper title, paper link, #co-author

It also depends on the amount of space available in your tweet - their names will be written on the paper itself in any case. At the very least, let them know that you are tweeting/posting the link/paper, which would give them an opportunity to retweet/share it.

Comment: Why not `paper title, paper link, @co-author`?

Answer (score 7):

Having trouble [considering so many coauthors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16759/is-there-an-inflation-in-the-number-of-authors-per-paper) with 140 characters? Link to the paper, which lists the coauthors. #winningatacademia

Answer (score 6):

I would mention your co-authors, but check with them about how they want to be "linked". Even if they have a Twitter or Facebook account, they may no longer use it, or they may use it for personal contacts only.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Omen.

Also add the following:

If you shorten the URL of your work (using bitly.com or something similar) and "twitterfy" the title (perhaps make a hashtag combining a few select words from your title and the subject e.g. #semweb_info_integration_newway), you should be able to cite at least 5 or 6 twitter handles easily. I am not sure facebook is a good idea, considering (IMHO) for a lot of people it is more of a personal medium.