# I am part of a “study team” that authored a paper. How do I list in in my CV?

Tags: cv, authorship, collaboration

I was a member of a study team that produced a couple of research papers.
The authors of the paper are, for example:

> Michael Jordan, Tiger Woods, John Smith and The ABC Study Investigators

In the acknowledgements, it reads:

> The ABC Study team consists of members from Harvard University (James Bond, Thomas Harper, David Price, and Jason Jolly)

(Suppose that my name is David Price.)

Can I list such papers in the publication list of my CV?
If not, how can I show that I participated in these research papers?

In PubMed, my name was listed as one of 'collaborators.'

Comment: You could mention this in the section where you talk about previous research activity, but if you are not on the author list it would be misleading to include it in your list of publications.

Comment: That is an interesting question, I wasn't aware of this practice (i.e. listing a "study team" as authors).

Comment: Partially relevant? http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/who-all-are-considered-authors-of-papers-written-on-behalf-of-a-research-group

Comment: There is a good reason why in some journals, _all_ members of the team have to be listed as authors, along with the team name; IMHO that's a good policy. This is different for books though, where teams or fictional characters are being used as authors; however, the book has its own editors and each chapter is authored by someone specific in the team.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consortium authors are authors as well, just much less "important" authors than the main authors.  The situation is in fact quite similar to being in the middle of a large author list (e.g., one of my papers where I am 12th out of 32 authors).

As such, you should list the paper in a way that is clear, transparent, and easy for a reader to understand its stated authorship.  Put the paper in your CV with the authors just as they appear in the standard citation, then add a note at the end of that citation that says you were part of the consortium authors.  Following your example:

> - Michael Jordan, Tiger Woods, John Smith and The ABC Study Investigators, "Totally Awesome Science," Journal of Irreproducible Results, 12(6), pp. 406-453, 2012.
>     *(Member of ABC Study Investigators)*

Answer (score -2):

You can switch to the citation style that allows this easily. I'll list two standard papers and a paper written in a team:

> *Study of DEF*. Journal of DE **15**(5):1388-1391, 2013.
>
> *Note on XYZ* (with J. Doe). Journal of XY **51**(3):820-840, 2014.
>
> *Note on KLM* (with J. Soe and Team ABC, as a member of Team ABC). Journal of KL **8**(1):1-15, 2015.

This is clear, you're not lying to anybody nor hiding any substantial information, yet the presentation of the publications is easy to read: (1) paper title; (2) authors; (3) journal specification.

Comment: This does not convey who is first author on "Note On XYZ", which in my field is critical information.

Comment: What style is this?