# How do I reference a publication in my CV where I am alphabetically listed as an author but the citation lists the organization?

Tags: cv, authorship

I recently was part of a large writing group that produced a publication. Authorship, including myself, is listed alphabetically in the acknowledgements however the group leadership chose to list the organization as the author in the citation/reference rather than acknowledge contribution for authors. I previously brought this up as a problem when there was a proposed order of authors and sent the group leadership standard criteria for authorship listing.

How can I list the publication in my CV?

Comment: Is the authorship listed in the paper, just not in the author field?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61648/19607 or https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1246/19607

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely keep the original reference format but could easily add a simple footnote/inline note to elaborate your involvement. I would do something along the lines of:

> [P7] Organisation name**. *Awesome paper written in large writing group*. Published in the Journal of Awesome Research [3.14], pp.200-222. 2017
>
> ** **Note:** Published under organisation name, I am listed as nth author and contributed x.

Comment: I thought about it, too. But, it has been found out that in certain fields, footnotes are read *first*. So, better avoid them.

Comment: @LeonMeier Only if you are in those fields.